# Difference between "as" and a colon to specify type?

Tags: f#

I originally thought "as" and the colon operator meant the exact same thing, to specify a type for a value or function. But I actually found an inconsistency:

```
type Uppercase = string -> string
let uppercase:Uppercase = fun n ->
    //code
```

This works fine. But then if I change the colon to "as"

```
type Uppercase = string -> string
let uppercase as Uppercase = fun n ->
    //code
```

It breaks, saying it doesn't know what type "n" is. Of course, I can just fix that by doing

```
type Uppercase = string -> string
let uppercase as Uppercase = fun (n:string) ->
    //code
```

And it's happy again. So, my question is, why is "as" different from colon and why does it seem F# can't do type inference when using "as"? Thanks.

Comment: The keyword `as` it's not the same as the one in C#. It has nothing to do with types in F#. It is used to bind an expression as a single value, very useful when using discriminated unions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`as` is used to name the result of a pattern match e.g.

```
let (a,b) as t = (1,2)
```

will bind `a` to 1, `b` to 2 and `t` to the whole pair. Therefore

```
let uppercase as Uppercase = fun n -> ...
```

binds the names `uppercase` and `Uppercase` to the function. In this function, the type of `n` is not specified so you get the type error.

`as` is therefore quite different from an explicit type declaration and can't be used interchangeably.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find documentation anywhere about what "as" did. I didn't know it did that!

Comment: It's a keyword so it's listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233249.aspx